# ubuntustudio os sharing to diskless PXE clients

Tags: networking, pxe

About 5 years ago in ubuntustudio there was a complete robust solution script to share the os on the main machine to any and all diskless PXE clients, but I cannot remember which version had that or what the correct terminology is. I wish I could contract a paid Ubuntu Consultant a decent hourly rate to implement it for me and publish my server live online, such that clients only need know my real ip address to use me via high speed fibre... the next killer app is an online live shared OS.